# how to get a conf.txt path in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, path, text-files, workspace

I have an eclipse project and in one folder there is a text file "conf.txt". I can read and write the file when I use the path on my Computer. But I have to write my own folders there as well, not only the workspace folders. 
So know I want to commit the program for others, but then the path I put in the program won't work, because the program is running on a different computer. 
What I need is to be able to use the file with only the path in my workspace.

If I just put in the path, which is in the workspace it won't work.

This is how my class File looks like.

```
public class FileUtil {

public String readTextFile(String fileName) {

      String returnValue = "";
      FileReader file = null;

      try {
        file = new FileReader(fileName);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);
        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
          returnValue += line + "\n";
        }
        reader.close();
      } catch (Exception e) {
          throw new RuntimeException(e);
      } finally {
        if (file != null) {
          try {
            file.close();
          } catch (IOException e) {
            // Ignore issues during closing 
          }
        }
      }
      return returnValue;
    }

public void writeTextFile(String fileName, String s) throws IOException {

    BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));
    try {
        output.write(s);
    }
      finally {
        output.close();
      }
  }

}
```

I hope someone knows what to do.

Thanks!

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you just want to use a relative path rather than a fully qualified absolute path? E.g. ./resources/conf.txt rather than C://Files/Resources/conf.txt

Comment: What kind of project?  Java Project, Dynamic Web Project, etc...

Comment: yes, that's what I meant. So what do I put in front of the conf.txt ?

Comment: Java Project, sorry, forgot to mention that.

Comment: @Annika Where is your `conf.txt` file? I mean is it in your project root folder or outside of the project folder? May be showing some code snippet with file location will help to resolve your issue.

Comment: the path in the workspace is /de.uhd.ifi.se.pcm.bppcm.ui/ProjectE1/conf.txt   so it's in the project "de.uhd.ifi.se.pcm.bppcm.ui" where my class is located, which is supposed to read/write the file

Comment: @Annika Show us what is your are passing for `fileName` in `readTextFile()` method.

Comment: @Smit I am passing the path. For now it is the String "conf.txt"

Comment: @Annika Look at the answer I have given below. It has some explanation to it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but I attached the screen shot with little bit explanation. Let me know if you have any question.

Your project is root folder here and images as resources folder from where you can access the file using relative path.

```
// looks for file in root --> file.txt
scan = new Scanner((new File("file.txt")));

// looks for file in given relative path i.e. root--> images--> file.txt
scan = new Scanner((new File("images/file.txt")));
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want your configuration file to be accessed through a relative path, you shouldn't need to add anything to the front of it. Assuming you're using a bufferedReader, or something of the sort it would look as simple as: `br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("config.txt"));`

This will cause a search of the runtime directory, making it so you don't have to fully qualify the path to your file. That being said you have to ensure your config.txt is within the same directory as your executable.

Comment: I do have that line. I posted in the Question what my class looks like, which has the methods to read/write the file.